# React Testing Library - testing hooks with React.context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-context, react-hooks-testing-library

I have question about react-testing-library with custom hooks

My tests seem to pass when I use context in custom hook, but when I update context value in hooks cleanup function and not pass.
So can someone explain why this is or isn't a good way to test the custom hook ?

The provider and hook code:

```
// component.tsx
import * as React from "react";

const CountContext = React.createContext({
  count: 0,
  setCount: (c: number) => {},
});

export const CountProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const value = { count, setCount };
  return <CountContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CountContext.Provider>;
};

export const useCount = () => {
  const { count, setCount } = React.useContext(Context);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setCount(50);
  }, []);

  return { count, setCount };
};
```

The test code:

```
// component.spec.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { act, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { CountProvider, useCount } from "./component";

describe("useCount", () => {
  it("should save count when unmount and restore count", () => {
    const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
      return <ContextStateProvider>{children}</ContextStateProvider>;
    };

    const Component = () => {
      const { count, setCount } = useCount();
      return (
        <div>
          <div data-testid="foo">{count}</div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const { unmount, rerender, getByTestId, getByText } = render(
      <Component />, { wrapper: Wrapper }
    );
    expect(getByTestId("foo").textContent).toBe("0");
    unmount();

    rerender(<Component />);
    // I Expected: "50" but Received: "0". but I dont understand why
    expect(getByTestId("foo").textContent).toBe("50");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `render`, the rendered component tree is like this:

base element(`document.body` by default) -> container(`createElement('div')` by default) -> wrapper(`CountProvider`) -> `Component`

When you `unmount` the component instance, `Wrapper` will also be unmounted. See [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/v12.1.4/src/pure.js#L78).

When you `rerender` a new component instance, it just uses a new `useCount` hook and the default context value(you doesn' provide a context provider for `rerender`) in the `useContext`. So the `count` will always be `0`. From the doc [React.createContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext):

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree.

You should NOT unmount the `CountProvider` wrapper, you may want to just unmount the `Component`. So that the component will receive the latest context value after mutate it.

So, the test component should be designed like this:

`component.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

const CountContext = React.createContext({
  count: 0,
  setCount: (c: number) => {},
});

export const CountProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  return <CountContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount }}>{children}</CountContext.Provider>;
};

export const useCount = () => {
  const { count, setCount } = React.useContext(CountContext);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => setCount(50);
  }, []);

  return { count, setCount };
};
```

`component.test.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { CountProvider, useCount } from './component';

describe('useCount', () => {
  it('should save count when unmount and restore count', () => {
    const Wrapper: React.ComponentType = ({ children }) => {
      const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);
      return (
        <CountProvider>
          {visible && children}
          <button data-testid="toggle" onClick={() => setVisible((pre) => !pre)}></button>
        </CountProvider>
      );
    };

    const Component = () => {
      const { count } = useCount();
      return <div data-testid="foo">{count}</div>;
    };

    const { getByTestId } = render(<Component />, { wrapper: Wrapper });
    expect(getByTestId('foo').textContent).toBe('0');

    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('toggle')); // unmount the Component
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('toggle')); // mount the Component again
    expect(getByTestId('foo').textContent).toBe('50');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/67749630/component.test.tsx (8.46 s)
  useCount
    ✓ should save count when unmount and restore count (54 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
 component.tsx |     100 |      100 |      80 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.988 s, estimated 9 s
```

Also take a look at this example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/67749630-wrj5im?file=/src/App.tsx)